# Why does my grappling gun stay attached when I swap weapons?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I shoot my grappling gun at a surface it works how it is supposed to but when I go to switch weapons I am still attached to the surface and I have to swap back to the grappling gun to detach myself from the surface. Does anyone know how I could make it so that I get detached when I swap weapons?

Here is the weapon switching code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour {

   
public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       SelectWeapon(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            else
                selectedWeapon++;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            else
                selectedWeapon--;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            selectedWeapon = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            selectedWeapon = 1;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3) && transform.childCount >= 2)
        {
            selectedWeapon = 2;
        }

        if (previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }

    }

    void SelectWeapon ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if (i == selectedWeapon)
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            else
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the grappling gun code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GrapplingGun : MonoBehaviour {

    private LineRenderer lr;
    private Vector3 grapplePoint;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
    public Transform gunTip, camera, player;
    private float maxDistance = 100f;
    private SpringJoint joint;

    void Awake() {
        lr = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            StartGrapple();
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            StopGrapple();
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate() {
        DrawRope();
    }

    void StartGrapple() {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(camera.position, camera.forward, out hit, maxDistance, whatIsGrappleable)) {
            grapplePoint = hit.point;
            joint = player.gameObject.AddComponent<SpringJoint>();
            joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            joint.connectedAnchor = grapplePoint;

            float distanceFromPoint = Vector3.Distance(player.position, grapplePoint);

          
            joint.maxDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.8f;
            joint.minDistance = distanceFromPoint * 0.25f;

        
            joint.spring = 4.5f;
            joint.damper = 7f;
            joint.massScale = 4.5f;

            lr.positionCount = 2;
            currentGrapplePosition = gunTip.position;
        }
    }


   
    void StopGrapple() {
        lr.positionCount = 0;
        Destroy(joint);
    }

    private Vector3 currentGrapplePosition;
    
    void DrawRope() {
        if (!joint) return;

        currentGrapplePosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentGrapplePosition, grapplePoint, Time.deltaTime * 8f);
        
        lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
        lr.SetPosition(1, currentGrapplePosition);
    }

    public bool IsGrappling() {
        return joint != null;
    }

    public Vector3 GetGrapplePoint() {
        return grapplePoint;
    }
}
```

Here is the grappling gun switching code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GrappleGunWeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       SelectWeapon(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            else
                selectedWeapon++;
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if (selectedWeapon <= 0)
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            else
                selectedWeapon--;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            selectedWeapon = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2) && transform.childCount >= 2)
        {
            selectedWeapon = 1;
        }

        if (previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }

    }

    void SelectWeapon ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if (i == selectedWeapon)
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            else
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my hierarchy:

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvXN8.png)

Thanks

Comment: A tip. You may have the itteration you have in SelectWeapon in the Start function instead and add all gameobjects to an List so you have to just itterate through the list. It may make it a little more clear in terms of readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `GrappleGunWeaponSwitching` Script is kind of redundant isnt it?

I would have 2 solutions for you I think. First of you could add the `OnDisable()` function (event) to the `GrapplingGun` Script and write something like this

```cs
void OnDisable() {
    StopGrapple();
}
```

The Problem with this is that each time you disable the Script it will also be triggered. But I guess that wont be a problem.

Another solution may be to add a `Gun` Parent Script where each of your guns is a Child from. This would look like `public class GrapplingGun : Gun {`.
Now you will be able to change this function in `WeaponSwitching`

```cs
    void SelectWeapon () {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform) {
            Gun gun = weapon.gameObject.GetComponent<Gun>();
            if (i == selectedWeapon) {
                gun.EnableEvent();
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            } else {
                gun.DisableEvent();
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Now you just need to add these two functions in the `Gun` Parent Class and overwrite it in each child so it will be called there. I hope you know some stuff about Polemorphy otherwise I may explain it to you.

Comment: The second solution is the more professional one btw.

Comment: I used the first solution and it worked thank you so much

Comment: @Josh_Stigzelius You welcome :D
Btw you may select my answere as the answere to your question so other people wont look at this thinking they have to add an answere xD

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a screenshot of your object hierarchy?

It looks like your SelectWeapon method iterates through child 'weapon' Transforms, so I'm guessing your weapon objects are children of the object with the WeaponSwitching script attached... is the Grappling Gun script attached to one of these child weapon gameobjects, or is it attached to the parent?  If it's attached to the parent then the weapon switching isn't turning it off.

In either case, you could have your WeaponSwitching script(s) run the StopGrapple method in your GrapplingGun script when switching weapons, which I think should do the trick?  Something like this:

```
public class WeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour {


public int selectedWeapon = 0; 
public GrapplingGun grapplingGun; // ADDED

void Start()
{
   grapplingGun = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<GrapplingGun>(); // ADDED
   SelectWeapon(); 
}
...

    void SelectWeapon ()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if (i == selectedWeapon)
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            else
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            i++;
        }
    if (grapplingGun != null) { grapplingGun.StopGrapple(); } // ADDED
    }
}
```

You'd also need to set your StopGrapple method to public.

If you thought you were going to run into similar issues with other weapons you could make your weapon classes derive from a master weapon class and define different specific outcomes for generically named methods (i.e, 'Activate' and 'Deactivate').  Then you could just process the 'Deactivate' method on all weapon children whenever weapons are changed.

Comment: Added a link to a picture of my hierarchy - thank you so much for the help